# Is there a means of stamping out IComparable<T> operator overloads without duplicating tons of code?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, icomparable

I've got a bunch of types that implement `IComparable<T>`. Because these types implement that interface, it makes sense to provide the following overloads:

```
/// <summary>Equality comparison operator.</summary>
/// <param name="lhs">The left hand side.</param>
/// <param name="rhs">The right hand side.</param>
/// <returns>True if <paramref name="lhs"/> is equal to <paramref name="rhs"/>; otherwise, false.</returns>
public static bool operator==(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null))
    {
        return object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null);
    }

    return lhs.CompareTo(rhs) == 0;
}

/// <summary>Inequality comparison operator.</summary>
/// <param name="lhs">The left hand side.</param>
/// <param name="rhs">The right hand side.</param>
/// <returns>True if <paramref name="lhs"/> is not equal to <paramref name="rhs"/>; otherwise, false.</returns>
public static bool operator !=(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

/// <summary>Less than comparison operator.</summary>
/// <param name="lhs">The left hand side.</param>
/// <param name="rhs">The right hand side.</param>
/// <returns>True if <paramref name="lhs"/> is less than <paramref name="rhs"/>; otherwise, false.</returns>
public static bool operator <(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    if (lhs == null)
    {
        if (rhs == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return lhs.CompareTo(rhs) < 0;
    }
}

/// <summary>Greater than comparison operator.</summary>
/// <param name="lhs">The left hand side.</param>
/// <param name="rhs">The right hand side.</param>
/// <returns>True if <paramref name="lhs"/> is greater than <paramref name="rhs"/>; otherwise, false.</returns>
public static bool operator >(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    return rhs < lhs;
}

/// <summary>Less than or equal comparison operator.</summary>
/// <param name="lhs">The left hand side.</param>
/// <param name="rhs">The right hand side.</param>
/// <returns>True if <paramref name="lhs"/> is less` than or equal to <paramref name="rhs"/>; otherwise, false.</returns>
public static bool operator <=(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    return !(rhs < lhs);
}

/// <summary>Greater than or equal comparison operator.</summary>
/// <param name="lhs">The left hand side.</param>
/// <param name="rhs">The right hand side.</param>
/// <returns>True if <paramref name="lhs"/> is greater than or equal to <paramref name="rhs"/>; otherwise, false.</returns>
public static bool operator >=(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    return !(lhs < rhs);
}
```

This is a lot of code to repeat over and over. Is there some means of creating an abstract class or something (e.g. C++'s `std::rel_ops`) which would make it easier to implement these?

Comment: I can't see how it makes any sense to implement all those operators.  IComparable<> requires only a *single* method to be implemented.  If you *have* to break it down (why?) then you only need the == and < operators to implement CompareTo().  Thinking about this in C++ may well be getting in the way.

Comment: @Hans: In C#, if you implement `==`, you *must* implement `!=`, or a compile error results. Same for `<` and `>`. If you implement `IComparable` and don't implement all these operators, FxCop yells.

Comment: Why are you talking about implementing operators?  IComparable doesn't require an operator at all.

Comment: @Hans: Yes, but FxCop does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182163.aspx

Comment: Sigh.  A robot will beat the stuffing out of common sense every time.  Just implementing IComparable to get an ordered collection isn't good enough I guess.

Comment: It's very rare that you should overload the == operator on reference types. "Most reference types, even those that implement the Equals method, should not override the equality operator (==)." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7h9bszxx(v=vs.100).aspx. " However, if you are implementing a reference type that is intended to have value semantics, such as a complex number type, you must override the equality operator." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx

Comment: @Jim: Again, I agree with you. But FxCop does not.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way, but I am not sure I would suggest it. In the example I only define two operators for brevity. In one of them, I cast the instance of `TemplateComparable<T>` to `T` because in the class constraints, `T` must indeed inherit from `TemplateComparable<T>` and the cast will be valid.

```
abstract class TemplateComparable<T> where T : TemplateComparable<T>, IComparable<T>
{
    public static bool operator ==(TemplateComparable<T> lhs, T rhs)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, null))
        {
            return ReferenceEquals(rhs, null);
        }
        return rhs.CompareTo(lhs as T) == 0;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(TemplateComparable<T> lhs, T rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }
}

class Foo : TemplateComparable<Foo>, IComparable<Foo>
{
    public int CompareTo(Foo other)
    {
        //Write your comparison code
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var v1 = new Foo();
var v2 = new Foo();
var equals = v1 == v2; //equals will be true
```

An alternative where `TemplateComparable<T>` implements `IComparable<T>` and `Foo` overrides its members:

```
abstract class TemplateComparable<T> : IComparable<T> where T : TemplateComparable<T>
{
    public abstract int CompareTo(T other);

    public static bool operator ==(TemplateComparable<T> lhs, T rhs)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, null))
        {
            return ReferenceEquals(rhs, null);
        }
        return rhs.CompareTo(lhs as T) == 0;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(TemplateComparable<T> lhs, T rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }
}

class Foo : TemplateComparable<Foo>
{
    public override int CompareTo(Foo other)
    {
        //Write your comparation code
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @BillyONeal It would work, but for me it seems a bit like a hack. It is not very readable and without proper documentation it could become unmaintainable. I'd use it with caution.

Comment: Why is the `rhs` param a `T` instead of a `TemplateComparable<T>`?

Comment: @juharr For simplicity. If you used `TemplateComparable<T>` you would have to cast it to `T` because `TemplateComparable<T>` doesn't implement `IComparable<T>`. You could make it implement that interface and implement the abstract members, then override them in your derived class, but I thought that it'd make the example too complicated.

Comment: @Eve: More unmaintainable than having the same 50 lines of code duplicated everywhere?

Comment: @BillyONeal It's my point of view, but while operator overloading add syntactic sugar to your code, the above example adds complexity to your classes and, in case you can't change your base types, it's even unusable. I'd say that it really depends on how useful it would be in your context. I understand that in your case it'd help to reduce your code's redundancy, I just think that it's better not to use without proper documentation.

Comment: @Eve: I agree with you. But FxCop does not: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182163.aspx

Comment: @BillyONeal I suppose that link refers to my choice to have `Foo` implement `IComparable<T>` rather than `TemplateComparable<T>`. I'll edit my post and add the alternative.